# Mocking TypeScript imports for Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am attempting to mock the import of a module for use in Storybook but I can only do it with JavaScript and CJS imports, not TypeScript and ESM. My current `webpackFinal` contains this

```
config.resolve.alias['moduleToMock'] = require.resolve('../src/mocks/mockModule')
return config;
```

This current config doesn't work with TypeScript and will throw an error saying that the mock module can't be found. How can I configure this to work with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

In general TypeScript only throws errors when you try to compile the code. If you encounter an error on code execution this is very likely more related to your code rewrite. If the `webpackFinal` of the Storybook already supports ESM and you need to import the module synchronously then you can create a replacement for the require function like this:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)

...

config.resolve.alias['moduleToMock'] = require.resolve('../src/mocks/mockModule')
```

Hope it helps.